# Differentiate between String and [Char]

Tags: haskell, types

I know that String is defined as [Char], yet I would like to make a difference between the two of them in a class instance. Is that possible with some clever trick other than using newtype to create a separate type? I would like to do something like:

```
class Something a where     
  doSomething :: a -> a

instance Something String where
  doSomething = id

instance (Something a) => Something [a] where
  doSomething = doSoemthingElse
```

And get different results when I call it with `doSomething ("a" :: [Char])` and `doSomething ("a" :: String)`.

I do know about `FlexibleInstances` and `OverlappingInstances` but they obviously don't cut the case.

Comment: You can't do this, at the compiler leve, `[Char]` and `String` are the exact same thing. Type synonym names go away. If you have to explicitly annotate anyways, why not use a newtype.

Comment: If you're interested in having different behavior for `Something=> [a]` and for `String` using haskell98 you might be able to do what the Show class does and use the [extra method trick](http://brandon.si/code/how-the-haskell-prelude-avoids-overlapping-types-in-show/)

Comment: Problem with that is that to my understanding it will always invoke the instance of `String` because `type String = [Char]`, so it doesn't really solve my case.

Comment: @qwe2 you're right, but I'd consider that sane behavior, not a problem :)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

That is not possible. `String` and `[Char]` are the same type. There is no way to distinguish between the two types. With `OverlappingInstances` you can create separate instances for `String` and `[a]`, but `[Char]` will always use the instance for `String`.

Comment: That's kind of what I expected. What do you think my best bet would be at solving the problem, though? Because all I can think of is introducing a `newtype` making them disjunct but that's not as pretty as I'd like it to be.

Comment: Use a newtype. This is the approach that std libs give

Comment: Better yet: if you're dealing with textual data, use the `Text` datatype. In this sense, you could consider it a pre-baked newtype wrapper around String, that happens to have a wonderful API and better performance.

Answer (score 4):

Why don't you define functions for each case:

```
doSomethingString :: String -> String
doSomethingString = id

doSomethingChars :: (Char -> Char) -> String -> String
doSomethingChars f = ...
```

Comment: Or (if there are more instances than just `[a]`) a single function for strings `doSomethingString` and keep the type class

Answer (score 1):

As said before, `String` and `[Char]` IS effectively the same.

What you can do though is defining a `newtype`. It wraps a type (at no-cost as it is completely removed when compiled) and makes it behave like a different type.

```
newtype Blah = Blah String

instance Monoid Blah where
  mempty = Blah ""
  mappend (Blah a) (Blah b) = Blah $ a ++ "|" ++ b
```